# fail the test case if the execution time exceeds the given value robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I am quite novice in RobotFramework. I want to set a timeout for my keyword to execute. If the keyword execution time exceeds the given timeout, then the test case needs to be failed. I tried to find relevant keywords. For example: Wait Until Keyword Succeeds or Wait Until Keyword fails. But I understood it so that, they are mainly used for retrying after given intervals or timeout. I do not want to retry, I just want to fail the case if the execution is not completed in given time.
Thanks in advance.

I have already tried with Wait Until Keyword Succeeds or Wait Until Keyword fails.

```
***  Test Cases  ***
Test 1
   [tags]  test1 
   Fail case in Performance not met

***  Keywords  ***
Fail case in Performance not met
   Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  60s  2s  keyword To Be Running

keyword To Be Running
   abc..........
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer after posting the question from another question. According to the robot framework user guide, the default timeout is 120 min and can be set separately in the settings. The summary of the findings are as follows in these examples:

---

```
*** Settings ***    
Test Timeout        20 minutes
```

---

The timeout can be set in a specified test case or keyword  with the [Timeout] setting:

---

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    [Timeout]            2 minute

***  Keywords  ***
Example1
    [Timeout]            5s
```

---

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a nice answer. If would be good if you could post a link to any referenced questions that are specifically mentioned as this might be useful to future readers. There is a hyperlink option `§` on the top bar of the editor. You can also use square brackets `[ text ]` followed by the actual address in parenthesis `( link )`.